# AngularJS - controllers communication

Tags: angularjs, controller

On my site I have the following structure

**Header_controller**:

```
myApp.controller('Header_controller',function($scope,$rootScope,$location,Genral_model){

    $scope.logout = function(){
        var data = {};
        $rootScope.$emit('logout_clicked', data);  // NOT WORKING
        $rootScope.$broadcast('logout_clicked', data); // NOT WORKING
    }

});
```

Users_controller:

```
myApp.controller('Users_controller', function ($scope,$rootScope,Users_model,$location,$state) {

    $rootScope.$on('logout_clicked', function(event, resp) {
        Users_model.unRegisterCookies();
    });
})
```

Users_model:

```
myApp.factory('Users_model', function($rootScope,$http,$cookies) {
  var factory={};

  factory.unRegisterCookies = function(){
      alert('log out');
  }


  return factory;
});
```

I'm trying to invoke `unRegisterCookies` function by sending broadcast from `Header_controller` to `Users_controller`, but it's doesn't work with emit and not with broadcast.

**How to make it work?**

Comment: Perhaps you can put the code on Plnkr.co or something so we can see it (not) working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this plnkr for working version of your code:

http://plnkr.co/edit/JN5yWBUjmjBh5m7FiQww

This is pretty identical to the code you posted and it's working.  You might have some other error in your page.  If you are in Chrome or FireFox, pull up the console and see what errors are being shown for your page.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.28"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular-cookies.js" data-semver="1.2.28"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="HeaderCtrl">
      <h1>Headers Controller</h1>
      <button ng-click="logout()">Log out</button>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="UsersCtrl">
      <h1>Users Controller</h1>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

script:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies']);

myApp.controller('HeaderCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {

  $scope.logout = function(){
      var data = {};
      $rootScope.$emit('logout_clicked', data);  // NOT WORKING
      $rootScope.$broadcast('logout_clicked', data); // NOT WORKING
  }  

});

myApp.controller('UsersCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, Users_model) {

  $rootScope.$on('logout_clicked', function(event, resp) {
      Users_model.unRegisterCookies();
  });

});

myApp.factory('Users_model', function($rootScope,$http,$cookies) {
  var factory={};

  factory.unRegisterCookies = function(){
      alert('log out');
  }


  return factory;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the same basic code you're trying and it's working for me.  Maybe there's an error somewhere else in  your code?

http://plnkr.co/edit/SADWwkZWztoVJVjv0tKt

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.28"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="HeaderCtrl">
      <p>Button has been hit {{counter}} times.</p>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="UsersCtrl">
      <button ng-click="pushme()">Count Me In</button>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

script:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('HeaderCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $scope.counter = 0;

  $rootScope.$on('countMeIn', function (event, data) {
    $scope.counter = $scope.counter + 1;
  });

});


app.controller('UsersCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {

  $scope.pushme = function() {
    $rootScope.$emit("countMeIn", {});
  };

});
```

Comment: Can you try to add an alert("HEY!") into your $scope.logout() function to make sure that's getting called.  If that works try putting an alert in  "$rootScope.$on('logout_clicked', function(event, resp) {" to make sure that's getting called.

Comment: logout is called but $rootScope.$on('logout_clicked', function(event, resp) doen't work